# While running an applet on the browser gives a run time error :- "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig"

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, applet

I have included all the jar files. This applet is actually calling a restful web service in the localhost only.When I am just running JarExampleApplet.java as "run-as applet", it is working fine.But when I am running it in Browser it is giving me a run time error **"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig"**

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter;
import com.sun.jersey.core.util.Base64;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")  
    public class JarExampleApplet extends Applet {

        public static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/RESTfulWS";
        public static final String PATH_NAME = "/file/upload_json/";

        public void init ()
        {
            JarExampleApplet my_client = new JarExampleApplet();
            File file_upload = new File("C:/Grails.pdf");
            try{

            my_client.sendFileJSON(file_upload);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
             System.out.println("Exception : " + ex);
            }   
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.drawString("This Applet was read from a .jar file.", 0, 25);
        }

        public void sendFileJSON(File file_upload) throws JSONException, IOException{

            ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
            Client client = Client.create(config);
            client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());

            WebResource resource = client.resource(BASE_URI);
            WebResource service = resource.path("rest").path(PATH_NAME);
            JSONObject data_file = new JSONObject();
            data_file.put("file_name", file_upload.getName());
            data_file.put("file", convertFileToString(file_upload));

            ClientResponse client_response = service.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, data_file);
            System.out.println(" "+client_response);
            System.out.println("Status: "+client_response.getStatus());

            client.destroy();

        }


        //Convert my file to a Base64 String
        private String convertFileToString(File file) throws IOException{
            byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());   
            return new String(Base64.encode(bytes));
        }
    }
```

////////////////////////HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<applet code="JarExampleApplet.class" archive="JarExampleApplet.jar" height="200" width="400"></applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any problem in the html, because I am only running it with the class file . I haven't made the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are missing the `jersey-client.jar` for the same.

[Download Link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjerseyclientjar.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the reply...but I have included all the jersey jar files.It is giving this error on the browser.When I am running the applet in my IDE (eclipse), then it is working fine.I don't know why it is not working on the browser.

Comment: I have included external jar like jersey-client, can it be creating the problem?

Comment: No you haven't.  The only Jar on the run-time class-path of this applet is `JarExampleApplet.jar`.